# операция prompt Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, prompt

У меня такая проблема:
Задано условие, что если число, вводимое пользователем будет меньше 18, то картинка должна скрываться, если больше или равно 18, то должно показываться снова. Но проблема в том, что я ввел число, все работает, но в последующие разы ввода числа, количество prompt увеличивается на 1, т.е приходится отвечать по несколько раз.

В чем причина этого явления?

```js
function hide() {
  var img = document.getElementById('HS');
  addEventListener("click", function() {
    var age = prompt("Укажите возраст: ");
    if (age < 18) {
      img.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else if (age >= 18) {
      img.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="hide()">Клик</button> <img style="width: 30px" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3a/49/c1/3a49c13b207c20bdf1fac243a9a8bc6b.png" alt="Error!" id="HS">
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос весь код текстом, а не картинками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас стоит вызов функции при клике `onclick="hide()"` . А в функции делаете так  `addEventListener("click", function() {....` При клике вы уже вызвали функцию

```js
function hide() {
  var img = document.getElementById('HS');
  var age = prompt("Укажите возраст: ");
  if (age < 18) {
    img.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else if (age >= 18) {
    img.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="hide()">Клик</button> <img style="width: 30px" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3a/49/c1/3a49c13b207c20bdf1fac243a9a8bc6b.png" alt="Error!" id="HS">
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, еще один вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы когда картинка пропала, нужно просто нажать на кнопку и она появится, а не снова вводить число?

Comment: @PanHegoWan пожалуйста